# Как изменить select на ul с помощью jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть `select`, но я не могу его сверстать, мне нужно его переделать в ul.

Comment: jquery form styler в помошь)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Принцип следующий:

1. Создаёте блок `div`, стилизуете его под `select`;
2. Создаёте список `ul`, стилизуете его под раскрытый список, задаёте ему абсолютную позицию под блоком из п.1, скрываете его;
3. Создаёте `<input type="hidden">`, который будет содержать значение вашего селекта;
4. Для блока из п.1 пишете функцию на событие onclick, которая показывает список из п.2;
5. Для элементов списка из п.2 пишете функцию на событие onclick, которая закрывает список, присваивает значение элементу из п.3 и меняет текст блока из п.1.

Это один из множество способов. Простор для кастомизации большой. В интернете можно найти готовые решения.